# How do I remove a local package installed with 'lein install'?

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

Leiningen offers the ability to add a project to the local repository, the help text is:

```
> lein help install
Install jar and pom to the local repository; typically ~/.m2.
```

Cautious of making a mess while experimenting, is there a way within Leiningen of managing the local repository? And removing packages installed by mistake?

For Maven, I did find [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358851/how-to-remove-jar-file-from-local-maven-repository-which-was-added-with-install#18105528) - which suggests deleting files, is that the best way? (And anything to be careful of if deleting manually?)

Comment: Actually this may come in handy https://stackoverflow.com/a/36698590/2568352

Comment: @Sus That's a good idea, and probably a better fit for my use case! I'd be still be interested if there was an elegant way to manage the local repository though.

Comment: ... although you still need to 'lein install' using checkouts. :-( :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just delete the relevant files under `~/.m2`; there's nothing to fear... (but fear itself)

Lein uses `~/.m2` for storing all dependencies locally